# Autocompleter / Remove API for Multiple Instances - Working with first dom instance only - jQuery - Tinymce 6

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tinymce-6

Needing to re-populate my Tinymce 6 Autocompleter cardmenuitems after initialization -- this allows editing, adding, and deleting cardmenu items.

There are multiple div elements with class 'freeText' in my dom.  All initialize Tinymce properly using the jQuery class selector:

$('.freeText').tinymce({...})

The Autocompleter works properly in all 'freeText' class div elements.

After editing the source of cardmenuitem data, I want to re-initialize the Autocompleter with the new data.  To accomplish the re-population, I remove the tinymce before re-initializing:

$('.freeText').tinymce().remove();

Re-initialization is done by calling the same function as when Tinymce was first initialized.

The re-populated cardmenuitems function as expected -- but only in the first '.freeText' div instance.  The remaining instances still function as before with the original cardmenuitems, so the failure seems to be the remove line.

Thanks!
Rob

It seems that the remove command is only reaching the first instance, but I am not seeing the reason.  This is likely a jQuery issue I am missing rather than Tinymce, but this is the only jQuery class selector failure so it seems interrelated....?